# Form sends info to database when page is updated or loaded

Tags: php, database, forms

Im trying to get a form saving my info in my database. My form below sends the code to the database but  if I update the page, reload it or lust load the page the info from the form is sent to my database.

It should Work this way, when you click "Submit" then the info is sent - and only when you click submit.

I think im missing some kind of valation or something!

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?
include "../config.php";

mysql_query("insert into profiles set name= '".$_POST["name"]."', age= '".$_POST["age"]."', text= '".$_POST["text"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."'");
?>
```

and my form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="myform" id="myform">
 name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
 age: <input type="text" name="age"><br />
 text: <input type="text" name="text"><br />
 country: <textarea name="country" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

What im I doig wrong? Please advice.

Comment: If this is really everything of your form/validation, you miss alot...

Comment: You don't have code validation, you are using mysql_ function (which is deprecated), you directly set $_POST global to go inside your database where if I write sql code it will be executed... 
Please SEARCH at google or here about PHP form validating etc..

Answer (score 0):

use `isset`
as

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="myform" id="myform">
 name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
 age: <input type="text" name="age"><br />
 text: <input type="text" name="text"><br />
 country: <textarea name="country" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit_name">
</form>
```

add `name` attribute to submit button

```
<?
include "../config.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit_name']))
{
mysql_query("insert into profiles set name= '".$_POST["name"]."', age= '".$_POST["age"]."', text= '".$_POST["text"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."'");
}
?>
```

Now your query run only when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your button with a name:

```
<input name="formSubmit" type="submit">
```

And then you can check if the button was actually pressed very easy

```
if(isset($_POST["formSubmit"]) == true) {
    mysql_query("insert into profiles set name= '".$_POST["name"]."', age= '".$_POST["age"]."', text= '".$_POST["text"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="myform" id="myform">
 name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
 age: <input type="text" name="age"><br />
 text: <input type="text" name="text"><br />
 country: <textarea name="country" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
include "../config.php";
 if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    mysql_query("insert into profiles set name= '".$_POST["name"]."', age= '".$_POST["age"]."', text= '".$_POST["text"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."'");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change submit button to

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit">
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST[btn]))
  {
  //write your query here
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code when saving to database

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO profiles ('name','age','text') VALUES ('".$_POST[name]."','".$_POST[age]."','".$_POST[text]."')");
```

fix action atribute on form without htmlspecialchars

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" name="myform" id="myform">
```